# redirect from a file to stdout

Tags: .net, io, io-redirection

I have a .NET program that reads in a compressed file with unknown format and writes the data into a much larger csv file.  Ultimately, I want to do some analysis of this data in R.  Right now, I can extract the compressed data and then read the csv file, but there are lots of data files and that's a lot of slow reading/writing/reading.  Now's a good time to mention that I'm actually calling this program on a Linux machine using mono and I don't have the source code.  Is there anyway to hijack the writing of the file and send it to stdout or have it write the file in memory instead of to disk?  I have tried various things with file descriptors with no luck so far.

EDIT:  I called lsof -p pid while the thing was running.  The output file descriptor is given as 4u.  Does the u (which apparently means read and write) mean that 4>&1 won't work?

Comment: *Why* do you want to have the output on `stdout` instead of in CSV-formatted files? You could always create a RAM disk, have the output CSV files created there, and then `cat` the CSV files to `stdout`... Btw. does that program allow you to specify the name of the output file?

Comment: The program does not allow me to specify the name of the output file.

Comment: I want the output on stdout because I can capture the output of the call using the system command in R without anything being written to disk and read back in.

Comment: RAM disk looks promising.  I need to read about that a bit.  Ultimately, I'm trying to avoid the slowness of too much disk i/o.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Linux `proc` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), you should be able to use the following file descriptors as aliases for standard output:

- `/proc/self/fd/1`
- `/dev/stdout`

Comment: If the output file is being opened as read AND write (which it is according lsof), would I be able to use these aliases to send the output to stdout?  I've already tried calling the command with 4>&1 which I thought would work.  Now I'm worried that that read/write status is preventing me from doing what I want.

Comment: Where did you read about this `4>&1`? First time I heard of it. And, if you cannot specify the output filename, then my answer will not work - it only works if you can specify the name of the output file.

Comment: Here's a site that talks a bit about redirection and describes the file descriptors:  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html.  File descriptors 0, 1, 2 are stdin, stdout, and stderr.  File descriptors 3-9 refer to the next files in order.  In my case, 3 refers to the compressed file being read and 4 to the file being written.  I thought adding 4>&1 after the command should redirect the file being written to stdout, but it doesn't work, possibly because that file has been opened for both reading and writing.

Comment: OK, true... I think it is likely that the issue for `4` is that this `4` is not the program's output file - it is pretty likely that file `4` is an assembly file loaded by Mono (remember, loading an assembly implies that that file is read), and it may be hard predicting in advance which file will correspond to the output file.

Comment: When I run lsof -p pid while the program is running it lists the eventually created output file by name with the file descriptor 4u, where the u means read/write; and it also lists the compressed file by name with the file descriptor 3r.  That seemed pretty suggestive about the file descriptors.  Is there another possibility?